# Apply bottom margins in Bootstrap 4 ONLY in xs (smartphone and iphone)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Getbootstrap.com instructs, for putting CSS `margin-bottom:4rem;` on, say, images

> The classes are named using the format `{property}{sides}-{size}` for `xs` and `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` for `sm`, `md`, `lg`, and `xl`.​

The problem is that using the xs format, `{property}{sides}-{size}`, which would be `mb-4`, will apply the same margin-bottom spacing to `sm`, `md`, `lg`, and `xl` as well.

Does anyone know a trick to apply the `margin-bottom` spacing in Bootstrap to `xs` and only `xs` screens? What I am looking for is something like an "if statement" in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Since the classes apply their styles in increasing screen size and CSS is cascading you can use the second class to override the first one. In your example that could be:

```
<div class="mb-4 mb-sm-0"></div>
```

which overrides the first class, when the second one activates.

```css
.mb-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .mb-sm-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-4 mb-sm-0"></div>
```

Comment: Good answer.  Very elegant.  Thank you.

Comment: I have a class say called `.content-box` and has much larger padding and is also used in a bunch of different scenarios. 

In one case I want to remove the top padding using `.pt-xs-0`

I had to write a few helper classes `.pt-xs-only-0` so that I could remove the padding on one breakpoint.

Comment: Clear and simple, effective. Thank you :)